# Prove that $(X - Y')' \cap \;(X-Z)' = X'\cup\; (Z-Y)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$X, Y, Z$ are subsets of the universal set. Prove using set identities and properties of set operations. Where $'$ is the complement.

$(X - Y')' \cap  \;(X-Z)' = X'\cup\; (Z-Y)$

Comment: @Member I have tried approaching in both directions. Starting on the left side: Alternative representation for x-y' and x-z', demorgans on both, distributive, and demorgan again. And the closet the other way, alternative representation, distributive, demorgans separately on each bracket and than more attempts were made. Everytime there is a complement somewhere it shouldnt be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that you know this, $(A-B)=(A \cap B') \cdots (1)$

$\;\;\;\;(X-Y')' \cap \;(X-Z)' $

$= (X  \cap Y)' \cap (X \cap Z')' (using (1))$

$=(X' \cup Y')\cap ( X' \cup Z)$ (using De' Morgan law)

$=X' \cup (Y' \cap Z)$ (Distributive law)

$= X' \cup (Z-Y) (using (1) backwards)$

Comment: Thank you. I was inputting the union and intersect wrong for distribuitve